# Is there any more elegant solution for this simple loop?

Tags: java, arrays, loops

Hello I'm new to programming, I'm trying to solve a problem in which I'm given an array of 10 random numbers and I have to say whether the `number` is in the array.

If it is - then the program has to show the message  "I found it!", and if it isn't - "That number is not in the array!"

I wrote this solution and I would like to know if there is a simpler and faster way to solve it (language Java)

input: one number and an array of numbers

```
int cont=0;

for(i=0; i<10;i++){
  if(numbers[i]==number){
    System.out.println("I found it");
    cont++;
    break;
  }
}
if(cont==0)
  System.out.println("That number is not in the array!");
```

Thank you for helping, sorry if it's really simple, but I'm a beginner.

Comment: It can be done better, for example by intuitive `break`ing the for loop when you find any occurance (as there is no point looking for more).

Comment: You are implementing a classic search algorithm.  If the random numbers aren't sorted, your solution is generally the most efficient (a linear search), provided that you add a `break`, as the other comment points out.  However, if the random numbers are sorted, then you can perform a binary search, which is logarithmic and much more efficient.  Here is an example of binary search: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/binary-search/.

Comment: Yep! Some tools I recommend checking out are [streams](https://winterbe.com/posts/2014/07/31/java8-stream-tutorial-examples/). You can do some really interesting things (such as this kind of search) with very little code.

Comment: I think that last condition should probably be `if (cont==0)`.  Or just use a `boolean` for this instead of a count.

Comment: You should return after the number is found. Then you don't need the if-statement at the end.

Answer (score 1):

try like this (Java 8 and later versions):

```
boolean contains = IntStream.of(numbers).anyMatch(x -> x == number); 
if(contains)
   System.out.println("I found it");
else
   System.out.println("That number is not in the array!");
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Streams everywhere, just because of they are *streams*, isn't a good idea and doesn't make code cleaner, nor does it always make it more readable or even more faster.

Your loop seems good and I don't think you can improve the performance here. The only thing I'd have changed is, that I'd have introduced the *found flag*, it's a bit less code.

```
boolean found=false;

for(i=0; i<10; i++) {
    if(numbers[i]==number) {
        System.out.println("I found it");
        found=true;
        break;
    }
}
if(!found)
    System.out.println("That number is not in the array!");
```